# Run DOS Command for a Time Limit

Tags: batch-file

I want to perform the following operations.

1. Read 1 word at a time from an input file consisting of many words.
2. Pass this word as an argument to another command line based application.
3. Run that application for a fixed amount of time, say 10 seconds.
4. Abort the execution of the application if it is still running after 10 seconds and go back, pick the next word from the input file and repeat steps 1 to 3.

Here is what I have written though it does not achieve exactly what I want it to:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('type input.txt') do call:Routine %%i

:Routine
set app="myApp.exe"
set limit=60

%app% %1
goto Delay

:Delay
ping localhost -n %limit% > nul
```

The above script will introduce the delay after the execution of myApp has completed. However, I want it to run myApp.exe for not more than 10 seconds, if it does, then abort the application using taskkill and move on to the next word from the input file.

I searched for a solution online and came across this:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/WinXP/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/2006-04/msg03609.html

Though it does not answer my query exactly, I would like to make my code do something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in the linked code looks flawed: It either launches 3 download commands, or it delays ~59 seconds and attempts to kill all download commands, but it never does both. The TASKKILL command arguments are not correct - the imagename belongs after the /IM parameter.

In your code, you are not going to kill your task without the TASKKILL command!

You must GOTO :EOF or EXIT /B after your loop finishes, otherwise the code will fall through and execute the subroutine without using CALL. But there really is no need to use a subroutine at all.

You only need to initialize your variables once.

No need to execute a command in your IN() clause. FOR /F has a variation that can read the text file directly. Type `HELP FOR` from the command line and read the documentation carefully.

PING has roughly a 1 second delay between each echo request. So a count of 11 will yield a delay of roughly 10 seconds.

*EDIT - originally forgot the critical START command to start the app in its own process*

```
@echo off
set app="myApp.exe"
set limit=11
for /f %%i in (input.txt) do (
  start "" %app% %%i
  ping localhost -n %limit% > nul
  taskkill /im %app% /f
)
```

Comment: In my case this is not working. The ping delay and taskkill are executed only after the application execution has completed. Ping delay does not start executing as long as the application is still running.

Comment: @NeonFlash - Oops, of course it's not working. I forgot the START command. I've edited the code in my answer.